# Действие при входящем звонке

Tags: android

Есть приложение, которое воспроизводит аудио. Необходимо чтобы при входящем звонке проигрывание аудио останавливалось. Как этого добиться?

Comment: Вам нужно [почитать](http://developer-android.unlimited-translate.org/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html) о классе AudioManager и аудиофокусе, связанном с ним

Comment: почитал, но не совсем понял как понять что поступил входящий звонок, чтобы приложение отреагировало и перестало проигрывать